# How do I know if my Koala global config is working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, config, koala

I've tried putting an API config property in both config/application.rb and config/initializers/koala.rb

```
    Koala.config.api_version = "v2.2"
```

How can i tell if it's using v2.2? the POST url isn't giving me any clues and the logs are giving any post params (i'm using put_connections so I don't think i can control that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Trust the initializer**

Open a `$ rails console` and check the attributes of the class Koala that has already been instantiated at run time by running  `$ Koala.config.version` you should see the value and that is what Rails will use.

When you start a rails console, it will load the environment in the same way as the rails server. Giving you a true representation in this case.

This would be enough proof for me, it is the only place defining a version **unless** you are defining it per request like the [docs](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) example:

```
 @graph.get_object("me", {}, api_version: "v2.0")
```

**Do some debugging**

If you really just want to see the number in use, use a gem called [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and add `binding.pry` just before you call the api. Try to run the code again but this time check your server logs and you now have an interactive shell for investigation.

Run your version of the following:

```
@graph.inspect
@graph.put_connections(...).inspect
```

This should give you a more detailed view of the request. Somewhere inside will hopefully be the version number.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small tweak to check my version in rails console - had to use Koala.config.api_version instead.

Koala.config.version returned nil.

I have my global setting in application.rb